# Why does this simple WHERE clause doesn't return any data?

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have a very simple table on BigQuery that I've created from another table. One of the fields is the `user_email` (string), which I've extracted from a JSON field with `JSON_QUERY(json_field, "$.email")`.

I would like to get some specific emails from the table with a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT user_email
FROM my_table
WHERE user_email IN ("blabla@example.com", "blabla2@example.com"...)
```

The emails in the list from above DO exist, but I'm not getting any results from the query.

Any idea?

Comment: can you check if `user_email ` data has spaces around it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **JSON_VALUE** instead of **JSON_QUERY** to extract a value as a BigQuery String. **JSON QUERY** returns a value as JSON-compatible String, not BigQuery String.

For example,

```sql
SELECT JSON_QUERY('{ "email": "blabla@example.com" }', '$.email') email;
```

[image]

Note that returned value is wrapped with double quotes.

But if you use **JSON_VALUE**,

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{ "email": "blabla@example.com" }', '$.email') email;
```

[image]

You can get a value without double quotes and be able to compare it with other BigQuery Strings **IN ("blabla@example.com", "blabla2@example.com"...)**